# How to wait for fetch api values to return prior to exporting constant object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, fetch

I have the following piece of code at the top level of my react component:

```
const myPriv = [];

export const myUserState = 
   {
     loggedIn: true,
     loggingIn: false,
     myPrivs: myPriv
   };
```

I am also performing the following fetch API call:

```
  const getPrivs = () => {
    const apiOptions = {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    };

    return fetch(`${MY_ENDPOINT}/getMyPrivs`, apiOptions)
        .then(handleErrors)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
          myPriv.push(json[0].privs)
        })
        console.log('myUserState values: ', myUserState );
        .catch((error) => {
         console.log(error));
        }
 }
```

The issue I am having is that my `myUserState.myPrivs` array value is empty as it seems to be getting set/exported prior to my fetch api call to `/getMyPrivs` completing and setting `myPriv` array that is getting assigned to `myUserState.myPrivs`.

Unsure if I'm able to perform some form of ternary operation on the export to only perform this until `myPriv` array is populated?

Can anyone please assist on how to wait for `myPriv.push(json[0].privs)` to be set prior to `myUserState` export occurring inorder to ensure that `myUserState.myPrivs` array value(s) are avaialble?

Comment: There is top-level await, but I think you've a larger logical issue here. `myPriv.push(json[0].privs)` looks to be a mutation, but it's unclear what `myPriv` is. If it's a global object then you should definitely rethink your app code structure. Can you describe your usecase or the the problem you are trying to solve with that export, or what you want to happen?

Comment: @DrewReese - this `myUserState` is being used as part of a `useContext()`. All I am attempting to achieve to simply be able to assign an array of privileges to `myPrivs` but it looks like `export const myUserState` is being executed first. But I want to be able to set the array values prior to export. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Just populate the array of privileges when the app mounts and you can make the asynchronous call to get them.

Comment: @DrewReese - apologies as I am a bit confused. how can I assign the privilges to `myUserState.myPrivs` export const, after I make the asynchronous call to get them?

Comment: `myUserState.myPrivs = .....`? ‍♂️

Comment: @DrewReese - are you saying, use a `useEffect()` to retrieve privileges via an asynchronous call and within this same `useEffect()`, assign the array to `myUserState.myPrivs` ? Is this correct?

Comment: Affirmative. When the app loads have the context provider use a mounting `useEffect` hook to make the call and populate the privileges.

Comment: @DrewReese - that did the trick - thanks.